# Mousewheel scroll fire only once next callback

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have Owl carousel setup like this

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div>0</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
</div>
```

this is the js

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items       : 1,
    singleItem  : true,
    rewindNav   : false,
    dots        : true,
});
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY<0) {
        console.log(e.deltaY);
        owl.trigger('next.owl');
    } else {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f0yph3aL/

as you can see if you scroll your mousewheel over the red square, the slides are moving like crazy. I need to have the next.owl.carousel fire only once so by mousewheel scroll it changes only +1 slide.

I have tried setTimeout inside the `owl.on`, tried `debounce` and `bind/unbind mousewheel`. Maybe I did it wrong. Thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE:**

Here is unbinded mousewheel, which works great but I don't know ho to bind mousewheel back on after some timeout `(setTimeout)` 
http://jsfiddle.net/cz122kk6/1/

Comment: It's working fine, may i know in which browser you are testing.

Comment: Opera, Chrome, FIrefox.. if I make big scroll with mousewheel it scrolls from 0 to 9.. but if I scroll just a little bit, it scrolls only one slide. I need to fire that trigger no matter how far I scroll the mousewheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the flag for transitions and change it in time transition starts/ends. Here is the script code:

```
$('.owl-carousel').each(function(i) {
    var owl = $(this);
    owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        singleItem: true,
        rewindNav: false,
        dots: true,
    });
    var allowTransitionLeft = false;
    var allowTransitionRight = true;
    owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            if( allowTransitionRight ) {
                allowTransitionRight = false;
                owl.trigger('next.owl');
            };
        } else {
            if (allowTransitionLeft) {
                allowTransitionLeft = false;
                owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            };
        }
    }).on('translated.owl.carousel', function (e) {
        allowTransitionRight = (e.item.count > e.item.index );
        allowTransitionLeft = (e.item.index > 0);
    });
});
```

You can see it in **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0yph3aL/9/)**.

When slide transition ends `translated.owl.carousel` event is fired. There we chose which transition is allowed based on Carousel's active item index.

The list of ***Owl Carousel 2*** events [here](http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html).

**EDIT:**
Now works for multiple instances.

Comment: There's a problem with multiple owl instances, check updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f0yph3aL/8/ , As you can see when you end up on 9th slide and go to another section, the mouse scroll isn't triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    items       : 1,
    singleItem  : true,
    rewindNav   : false,
    dots        : true,
    loop: true,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
});
```

Done :)

Comment: Nope :( If I scroll mousewheel from top to bottom, it fires two times, so no, slowing slide speed isn't solution. I know the trick is in deltaY (mousewheel).